# Separate Lagom write / read sides into separate services?

Tags: lagom

I've taken a look at a few demos, including the Chirper demo app: 
https://github.com/lagom/lagom-java-sbt-chirper-example

Adding a chirp and retrieving a live stream of chirps is added to the same service. This seems to be common practice:

```java
public interface ChirpService extends Service {

  ServiceCall<Chirp, NotUsed> addChirp(String userId);

  ServiceCall<LiveChirpsRequest, Source<Chirp, ?>> getLiveChirps();

  ServiceCall<HistoricalChirpsRequest, Source<Chirp, ?>> getHistoricalChirps();

  @Override
  default Descriptor descriptor() {
    // @formatter:off
    return named("chirpservice").withCalls(
        pathCall("/api/chirps/live/:userId", this::addChirp),
        namedCall("/api/chirps/live", this::getLiveChirps),
        namedCall("/api/chirps/history", this::getHistoricalChirps)
      ).withAutoAcl(true);
    // @formatter:on
  }
}
```

My question revolves around the idea that you could submit the `addChirp` message to a topic of a message broker (Kafka process) with the purpose of decoupling reads from writes. That is, the write will return a success even when the read-side (consumer) is temporarily unavailable (i.e., the chirp gets temporarily stored by Kafka to disk, to be processed by the read-side once it is available again).

Wouldn't it be logical to separate the write-side from the read-side into separate services and run them on different ports altogether? Or does this approach have common pitfalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing `read-side`'s in Lagom you have two options:

- Intra-service read-side: uses Akka Persistence Query to read directly from the Journal of the write-side and build a read-side. The operation to obtain the new events, track the offset (to know which events were read already) and create your read-side tables happens in-process, and, most relevant, the offset tracking and the user-table update happen in-transaction offering `effectively-once` semantics. The other advandtage of intra-service read-sides is that modelling stays behind doors and you can refactor your tables freely as long as the public REST endpoints offer the same API.
- Inter-service read-side: (aka remote read-sides) the alternative implies creating a remote service and publish events from the origin service into a broker so the remote service can consume them. This has some caveats: (1) the events are now public and therefore public API isn't as easy to refactor, (2) publishing is not transactional and consuming may be either `at-least-once` (what you generally want) or `at-most-once` so the end-to-end guarantees are no longer `effectively-once`, (3) the topic is accessible by other services (this isn't bad, it's just an extra consideration), (4) write-side and read-side live in different services which is a bit unnatural.

There's a demo of a remote read-side in [`online-auction-java`](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java) demo app: the `search-service` is a remote read-side that consumes events from many topics consolidating information into a single elasticsearch index. In this case it makes a lot of sense to use a remote read-side because: (a) we're using a specific storage tech (elastic search) and (b) we're merging streams coming from two different upstream services.

HTH,